# How can I show drafts in wp_dropdown_pages list?

Tags: plugins, custom-field, pages, filters, dropdown

I am using `wp_dropdown_pages` in the backend of my site to generate a list of pages according to a specific set of criteria.

The list only shows ***published posts*** where I would like it to show both published posts ***and drafts***.

I have found other Stack Exchange threads which show how to accomplish this in the standard wordpress dropdowns, but this does not seem to extend to `wp_dropdown_pages`.

What I am using to show drafts in the standard dropdowns is this:

```
<?php
    /* Show drafts in dropdown lists */
    add_filter('page_attributes_dropdown_pages_args', 'my_attributes_dropdown_pages_args', 1, 1);
    add_filter('quick_edit_dropdown_pages_args', 'my_attributes_dropdown_pages_args', 1, 1);

    function my_attributes_dropdown_pages_args($dropdown_args) {
        $dropdown_args['post_status'] = array('publish','draft');
        return $dropdown_args;
    }
?>
```

The above works great. I would like to do exactly the same thing for custom fields generated using `wp_dropdown_pages`. To clarify, in the backend, I am generating a dropdown list using the following code:

```
<?php
    $dropdown_args_food = array(
        'depth'         => '2',
        'selected'      => $selectedFoodType,
        'post_type'     => 'page',
        'name'          => 'selected-food-type',
        'id'            => 'selected-food-type',
        'echo'          => 1,
        'meta_key'      => 'category',
        'meta_value'    => 'food',
        'hierarchical'  => 1,
        'show_option_none'      => ' ',
    );
    wp_dropdown_pages( $dropdown_args_food );
?>
```

The above generates a dropdown list of pages exactly as I want it to be, only without drafts.

Comment: You can't pass post_status as argument to wp_dropdown_pages() your options would be to generate the posts from get_posts() or WP_Query custom query in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

It seems that you can do this directly with WP function `wp_dropdown_pages()` as birgire points out in his response below:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/240275/102371

---

This solution is longer, and uses get_posts() to fetch specific post statuses.

```
$pages = get_posts( array( 'post_type' => 'page', 'post_parent' => 0, 'post_status' => array( 'draft', 'publish' ) ) );

echo '<select name="selected-food-type" id="selected-food-type">';
foreach( $pages as $page ) {
    echo '<option value="' . $page->ID . '">' . get_the_title( $page->ID ) . '</option>';
    $children = get_children( 'post_parent='. $page->ID );
    foreach( $children as $subpage ) {
        echo '<option value="' . $subpage->ID . '">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' . get_the_title( $subpage->ID ) . '</option>';
    }
}
echo '</select>';
```

Comment: Thanks for this - it's fantastic. I hadn't considered using something besides wp_dropdown_pages and had been wrestling with that rather than looking for other solutions! It works perfectly.

Comment: birgire's answer below should be the accepted answer, uses less code and direct WP API : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/240275/102371

Comment: @AhmedMahdi Your approach has few benefits though, to be fair. It can e.g. support multiple post types and handle non-hierarchical post types. So that's why I already upvoted your answer as an alternative. There are therefore pros/cons to both methods, depending on  what the user wants  ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use

```
'post_status' => 'publish,draft',
```

in `wp_dropdown_pages()` since it's a wrapper for `get_pages()` that supports the `post_status` argument with comma separated list of post status types.

**About the documentation of `get_pages()`:**

It looks like the documentation for the `post_status` argument of `get_pages()` isn't accurate enough. It says:

```
* @type string  $post_status  A comma-separated list of post statuses types to include.
```

But it does actually support an array as well, so we can write:

```
'post_status' => [ 'publish', 'draft' ],
```

I filed ticket [#38136](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/38136) to address that.

Comment: am little confused excuse me, so does it currently work? (just not documented)

Comment: it should work, but isn't documented. Did you test it? @AhmedMahdi

Comment: yup that's much cleaner / quicker. i was not aware of this, though the documentation needs to be updated really for issues like these.

Comment: yes, we should keep in mind that the documentation isn't always accurate, but it's getting better   @AhmedMahdi